# Starting with Safari 11 by blocking autoplay HTML5 Audio, this means also it blocks features like: repeat, shuffle, or playlist?

Tags: javascript, html, audio, safari, autoplay

Last year Safari 11 blocked autoplay for HTML5 Audio:
https://webkit.org/blog/7734/auto-play-policy-changes-for-macos/

- Most of the info is about video autoplay which is allowed if is
  muted,
- **Audio is not allowed to autoplay**, which is fine.

User needs to perform an action (click / tap) to play which is also fine but.... this blocks any playlist feature to play next track or shuffle or repeat because they are considered autoplay even if the user performed an action initially.

**There is any solution to have audio features like playlists (to play next track automatically) or repeat for Safari?**

Because code was requested:
https://github.com/arielfaur/ionic-audio/tree/3.0

Demo: https://arielfaur.github.io/ionic-audio-demo/
Try to build a playlist and let it play next track.

Chrome is following:
https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/audio-video/autoplay

Comment: Hmm... this is interesting... I can assure you this is possible. [YouTube](http://youtube.com) should be an example

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, through js.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, your statement is not correct. Once a MediaElement has been marked as allowed by a user-gesture, then you can fully interact with it later on. The trick is to reuse the same Element that got the approval.

Comment: @GrantGarrison: Yoou are right, just because Safari allowed that specifically for "some" websites ;) one of them is YouTube

Comment: Won't close before you agreed, but have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483001/programmatically-play-video-with-sound-on-safari-and-mobile-chrome/46483345#46483345

Comment: @Kaiido: If any promise is involved the play is not allowed, doesn't matter if the MediaElement has been clicked. Any repeat, shuffle, playlist next track involves a promise.

Comment: @Kaiido shouldn't OP edit to add JavaScript?

Comment: @Kaiido: That is video, video is allowed, we are talking about Audio here.

Comment: Ok, so [tag:player] is a being cleaned, so I swapped that for [tag:javascript]. If there is a dupe that should help @Augustin

Comment: No this restriction is set on the MediaElement level. You can play audio files in a `<video>`. I absolutely don't get what you are saying about *promise*. This restriction will get leveraged as soon as you call `play` inside a trusted event, and for the whole life of this element, even if you do change its src.

Comment: @Kaiido: IF video is not muted is not autoplayed, so audio in <video> wouldn't allow autoplay.

Comment: If MediaElement has been approved by an user-gesture, then you can do whatever you want with it... muted or not. https://jsfiddle.net/m0da04at/

Comment: try Opera mini. It works great. Opera mini in ios supports autoplay by default, while chrome, firefox and safari does not and have not offering options to turn on.

Comment: Just ranting but I was actually using multiple audio tags to work around bugs in browsers that didn't like me changing the src related to things like `createMediaStreamSource`. Hopefully those bugs are fixed so I can adapt my app to use just one audio element.