# Audio not play on mobile browser on load

Tags: html, audio

I am trying to play audio while page is load

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <audio controls id="my_audio">
      <source src="bg.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload = function() {
        alert("ok");
        document.getElementById("my_audio").play();
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when i run this code in my computer's browser it works perfect but when i run same line in android chrome browser it displays alert but audio not play..

Please give some hints to do this..

Comment: you need an user gesture.

Comment: means?? sorry i can't understand. Can u please explain?@Kaiido

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46483001/3702797 talks about that

Comment: i write like this `setTimeout(function(){alert("play"); document.getElementById("my_audio").play().catch(console.error)}, 500);` but not works in android browser...@Kaiido

Comment: No, you need to call `play` from an user-gesture, e.g from a click event.

Comment: means i have to physically touch on play button.. audio not played like this? and i also try to play audio with button click and set trigger event that also not work....@Kaiido

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171048/discussion-between-wos-and-kaiido).