# User gesture is needed to Audio.play() - How to handle many audios to play as playlist?

Tags: javascript

Mobile browsers like Samsung Internet Browser refuse to perform HTMLAudioElement.*.play() method when I call it from any callback (ajax / audio.onEnd / interval / timeout and similar). So - how to handle playing consecutive audios in the playlist? When the first audio is finished, I would like to skip to the next audio in the playlist - immediately.

Today I get the exception like "User gesture is needed to Audio.play()". My first approach is to use first user action (like "PLAY PLAYLIST" button) to download all the audios from the playlist and call them to play & pause, and store them in the cache to re-play().

```
button.click(ev=>{
 ...
 for(....) {
       $("<audio>"). **** .appendTo(place);
       ...
       audio.play();
       audio.pause();
       cache.put(audio);
 }
 ...
});
```

But the drawback of this approach is to download all audios (for example 80 audio files).

Is it possible not to download all 80 files and call play&stop and download the audio file only then when I call the play - as the second step (when I need it to play)?

Any other solutions?

Comment: I didn't tried on all browsers that do expose such a limitation, but on all that I tested (desktop Safari, mobile & desktop Chrome), once a MediaElement has been marked as *user-gesture safe*, it will remain in this state.  

This means that you can very well have all your playlist to work on a single `<audio>` element, and be able to control it via scripts.  
You'd just change its src when needed.

[almost dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483001/programmatically-play-video-with-sound-on-safari-and-mobile-chrome/46483345#46483345) (check the end paragraph)

Comment: WOW - So you suggest I can replace audio.source.src URL of this audio and play it? When the new file is downloaded? After setting URL to the src attribute or after calling play() method - and the browser notices that the URL is changed and then download it? Interesting solution. I'm wondering it works on all browsers. Thank You !

Comment: It works (changing SRC). Thanks.